# my defined php function not working

Tags: php

I want my page to display an error message "lorem ipsum" if the input for $a  (from the $_POST super global) is greater than a defined maximum value ($max1 and $max2). So this is what I did:

```
$max1 = 2.7432;
$max2 = 274.32;
$a = $_REQUEST['a'];

    function maximum(){
        if ($a>$max1 || $a>$max2){
            echo "<script language=javascript> alert(\"Lorem Ipsum\");</script>";
            return maximum();
            } 
        }
```

then I call the function here like so:

```
 if(($fred=="fred") && ($george=="george") {    
            //check validity of input first by calling maximum;
            maximum();
}
```

This is not working! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a scope issue. `$a`, `$max1`, and `$max2` is not in scope inside of your function. You need to pass it as a parameter for it to be available (i.e. in scope) within your function.

Also, your function doesn't work. In a nutshell you need to return the string from your function and then capture or echo it out when calling the function.

```
$max1 = 2.7432;
$max2 = 274.32;
$a = $_REQUEST['a'];

function maximum($a, $max1, $max2){
    if ($a>$max1 || $a>$max2){
        return "<script language=javascript> alert(\"Lorem Ipsum\");</script>";
    } 
}

if(($fred=="fred") && ($george=="george")) {    
    //check validity of input first by calling maximum;
    echo maximum($a, $max1, $max2);
}
```

Comment: still $max1 $max2 Undefined variable

Comment: it doesn't seem to work properly though. It calls the function irrespective of whether the arguments has been met or not. So the javascript keeps showing irrespective. Please help

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot this? What value of `$a` are you using?

Comment: interestingly the echo value of $a is the deliberate small values I set. In the first instance, I set $a to "2" yet I still get javascript message alert

Comment: [Works for me](https://eval.in/262042)

Comment: like he said, it's a scope problem! Insert `$max1 = 2.7432;`
and `$max2 = 274.32` in the function. That should work!

Answer (score 0):

Please change your function like bellow and check the comments what mistake you did

```
    function maximum()
    {
        global $max1,$max2,$a;//make $a,$max1,$max2 available inside this function
        if ($a > $max1 || $a > $max2) {
            echo "<script language=javascript> alert(\"Lorem Ipsum\");</script>";
            //return maximum(); remove this line. Otherwise itwill go infinte loop
        }
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php